# Count the number of documents that have unique *values* in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Assume that my index contains  documents of the following form:

```
{
   "_id": "IDIDIDIDID"
   "IP": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
   "NetworkID": "foobar"
}
```

I want to count the number of unique combinations of `(IP, NetworkID)`. I know how to do it (approximately) for a single field: [cardinality aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html). I don't know how to do it for multiple fields. Is there a way to do it directly using elasticsearch or is the only way is an offline processing?

Comment: I think you either described incorrectly the requirement, or you are mixing up things. cardinality is for counting unique values. But in your post you are saying "count documents for which pair (IP, NetworkID) is the same" which is not the same as counting *unique* combinations of (IP, NetworkID). You say you want number of documents that have the same IP and NetworkID.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion below? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a script for the same cardinality aggregation that you mentioned:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "cardinality": {
        "script": "doc['IP'].value + ' ' + doc['NetworkID'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like it is doing the trick. Would you please briefly explain the script? Does it return a `string`? How does it work?

Comment: The uniqueness is given by the string combination IP + NetworkID and the aggregation is performed on this combination.